# Option key no longer showing relative spacing and position in Xcode

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Normally in interface builder you can click on an object, press the option key, and it would show the spacing between itself and other objects with red lines and red type. This has mysteriously stopped working for me in Xcode 6.4. Any fixes out there?

Comment: can you find any shortcut for it?

Comment: @kakajan I did not find a solution to this issue in Xcode 6.4. Upon installing Xcode 7 everything went back to normal

Comment: thanks, let me update it too :D, answer your own question, so others know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution to this issue in Xcode 6.4. Upon installing Xcode 7 everything went back to normal.